How to derive a generalized equation with respect to time for voltage across the inductor & current in an RL circuit with a DC PWM source?
Circuit connection:
I have this resistor (96 Ω)-inductor (990 µH) circuit connected to a PWM source of frequency 62.5 kHz; And amplitude 12 V, And it has the duty cycle of 44.140625%, and the ON time = 7E-6 sec & OFF time = 9E-6 sec so the period is 16E-6 sec. The circuit looks something like this:

And the MOSFET is connected to the MCU (ATmega328P).
As of now what I have:
As we know we derive the change in current/voltage with the help of time constant equation,
\begin{align}
 Change &= (Final - Start)(1-e^\frac{-t}{\tau}) \\\\
 Current &= (\frac{12}{96} - 0)(1-e^\frac{-Rt}{L}) \\\\
 C(t) &= (0.125)(1-e^\frac{-Rt}{L}) \\\\
 Voltage &= (0 - 12)(1-e^\frac{-Rt}{L}) + 12 \\\\
 V(t) &= (-12)(1-e^\frac{-Rt}{L}) +12 \\\\
\end{align}
Current(time) = Graph of C(t) on desmos
Voltage(time) = Graph of V(t) on desmos
So both the equation of current and voltage doesn't consider the PWM frequency and duty cycle!
Question:
What I am trying to derive is an generalized algebraic equation for the voltage drop across the inductor and current in this circuit as a function of time? Is there a way to model PWM function in this equation? Just like sine function can model repeating sinusoidal functions.
I am hoping to see something like this on my desmos graph-
Voltage:

(image source: google)
Current:

(image source: google)
Yes these are oscilloscope observations. But I am desiring for algebraic equations...

Why can't you use $V = L\cdot\dfrac{di}{d}$?

In power electronics, when describing switched converters (mainly inductive) which contain the duty cycle in their formulation, it is more common to involve average and maximum values of currents and voltages, slope for the inductor current and areas. Instantaneous values of periodic functions based on an initial time are less useful and difficult to manipulate (it would be about defining functions by switching intervals - picewise, for example).

@Andyaka I guess because this equation is applicable for a continuous-uninterrupted source voltage. And not for a PWM source, means it doesn't work in the time domain considering we have a square wave.

That equation will work in all circumstances.
